# Meaning of 拳の山の骨

Tags: meaning, words, manga, sports, metaphor

In a manga, a spectator is describing the way a boxer throws his punches:

> 拳の山の骨で斬【き】りにきよる…　物騒なヤツや

What is the meaning of 拳の山の骨? Does it refer to the knuckles? [Here you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCFrR.jpg) the page it is taken from. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

拳 is "knuckle", so 拳の山 should refer to a part of a knuckle. Judging from the picture, 拳の山 seems to refer to the protrusion made by the [metacarpophalangeal joints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacarpophalangeal_joint). 拳の山 is not a well-known term at least among laypeople. It doesn't look like boxer jargon, either. <del>so perhaps it's a made-up word.</del> Some orthopedists seem to use this phrase. Anyway, this is not to be memorized but to be understood ad-hoc.